# Firebase Analytics and App Tracking Transparency

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, ionic-appflow, apptrackingtransparency

I am working on an Ionic Project. On uploading the project to Apple using Ionic Appflow build it got rejected and yells the **"App Tracking Transparency Framework"**

> - Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
> We're looking forward to completing
> our review, but we need more information to continue. Your app uses
> the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we are unable to locate the
> App Tracking Transparency permission request. Since you indicated in
> App Store Connect that you collect data in order to track the user, we
> need to confirm that App Tracking Transparency has been correctly
> implemented.
>
> Next Steps
> Please explain where in your app we can find the App
> Tracking Transparency permission request. The request
> should appear before any data is collected that could be used to track
> the user.

Now I have found this article [App Store Rejection - Guideline 5.1.2 - Legal - Privacy - Data Use and Sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351633/app-store-rejection-guideline-5-1-2-legal-privacy-data-use-and-sharing) which states that he had it approved only when setting up the *App Store Connect*'s userIDs to *Used for App Functionality*.

What I want to know is:
Could you check both Firebase Analytics and App Functionality at the same time?
Would it require AAT when using Firebase Analytics that is used within the app only?

[Can you check this both?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuE1Y.png)